# calling image from css to javascript and adding integer value

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, image, background-image

I have a background image on css (uploaded from a file) and i need to put it in my javascript file and add an integer value to it and maybe put it in the array (optional if beneficial). I want to add an integer because every time i click this particular image, it will be added to the "score" section (already set).

is there a possible way to do it?

here's a snippet of the code:
css

```
div#gamearea4x4 div.row1#ga4r11{
    background-image: url(../graphics/8.png);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
```

and various tries with the javascript:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById("#ga4r11").style.backgroundImage;
img.value = "8";
```

or

```
var logo = $("#ga4r11").css('background-image').value = "8";
```

Comment: i've tried researching a lot, one being: var img1 = document.getElementById("#div id").style.backgroundImage; and it doesn't work

Comment: for now i just want to get the background image from css to javascript

Comment: Is the image transparent to see a background image?

Comment: Show what you've got so far using something like http://jsfiddle.net, I can't tell what you're really looking for between the question/body and the comments

Comment: alright, i added it on the description :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an you add the integer to the div where you put the image in? This may be what you are looking for:

```
var int = 8;
$("#ga4r11").css('background-image', '/'+int+'.png').attr('value', int);
```

This way you can set the integer dynamically. 
Every time you someone clicks on the image / div:

```
$('#ga4r11').on('click', function(){
    int++;
    $("#ga4r11").attr('value', int);
});
```

If you want it more dynamic, you can set the div id's dynamically as well:

```
var int = 8;
var image_id = "image_" + int; 
$("#"+image_id).css('background-image', '/'+int+'.png').attr('value', int)
```

You'll have to class all the image id's ( like

```
<div class="images" id="image_x">
```

) Then call if you click on the class:

```
 $('.images').on('click', function(){
    int++;
    $(this).attr('value', int);
});
```

That will then set the correct value for the correct id.

Comment: this really helped! thank you so much! is it still possible if i don't use a div id or class? (cause the div id will be randomized so it will have different images)

Comment: I'll edit the solution so you're allowed to do that too :)